# Elasticbeanstack instance Not able to collect to RDS of AWS

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a microservice into AWS Elasticbeanstalk using tomacat server as the platform. My instance has gone to warning state now. When i call the rest GET method, i can see that my code is not able to make a connection to MYSQL which is also an instance in AWS.
Below is the error am facing

> Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2103)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
>
> ...............
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection
>   timed out)    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:244)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:280)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2026)

However the same code if i run locally on my laptop, i can connect to RDS which is on AWS and get the desired output.

I have alsoattached AmazonRDSFullaccess policy to the role that is generated against elasticbeanstalk instance. But issue still exists.

Need help in resolving this. Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks for me as an issue with security groups for RDS instance.

Comment: Anything that i need to change here?

Comment: Well now am not even able to connect from laptop as well. Same error

Comment: Did you run RDS instance from AWS EB service? Or it's separate? 
This might be useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html

Comment: It was issue with security group. Above link worked

Comment: As the first comment says most probable issue wold be security group which is not allowing connection to RDS , Whitelist the sg group of elastic beanstalk and try to run it again , hopefully it will work !